# Bind Enter Key in Textbox to specific button

Tags: iframe

i have tried every possible script on StackOverflow but nothing is working.I want to bind enter key to a textbox , which clicks the specific button.
Code looks like this:

```
<form>
Enter URL: <input type="text" id="url" />
<input id="button" type="button" value="Load" onclick="loadUrl()" />
</form>
<iframe id="showUrl"></iframe>
```

button leads to another script for loading URL (which is working absolutely fine).But when i use any javascript or jquery, nothing happens, it shows "?" in main browser URL and my link from textbox disappers.

Sorry i am noob in programming, please help me

My loadUrl() Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadUrl() {
var url = document.getElementById( 'url' ).value,
    showUrl = document.getElementById( 'showUrl' );
showUrl.src = /$https?:\/\//.test(url) ? url : 'https://'+url;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post the loadUrl() script?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
function loadUrl() {
    var url = document.getElementById( 'url' ).value,
        showUrl = document.getElementById( 'showUrl' );
    showUrl.src = /$https?:\/\//.test(url) ? url : 'https://'+url;
}
</script>
`

Comment: Not in comment, in your question, nicely formatted. I the script you reference a 'showUrl'. I don't see that in your html.

Comment: I think your regex is wrong should be /^https:\/\//.test(url) ...but I'm just guessing that you're looking to see if the url starts with https.

Comment: What is document.getElementById( 'showUrl' )? What element is it? an iframe?

Comment: yes, i want to force users to use https://

Comment: yes, its an iframe, i want to put url in iframe, that comes from text bar

Comment: I would avoid doing a regex like that. You're not even removing http if it is there. For example if the url is http:// example.com, you're making it https:// http:// example.com. You might want to use the URL() class to parse the Url for you. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL. You can then rebuild the url from there.

Comment: The problem is of new Enter Script, if you can bind enter key to this URL box, which triggers load button, i'll be very helpful to you. if you see any problem in regex, please answer it in its column.  :)

Comment: Here take a look at this plunker i created. Maybe it'll put you down a better path. https://plnkr.co/edit/Ltxmbb2YZHqI62kEBpzh

Comment: Ehh okay. I'll make this an example and bind the enter key. Give me some time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the example on [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/wFWMz5d6HR0yEd78I8pF). If you create the form correctly it should automatically submit when you press the enter key, or click the Go/submit button.

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <form id="theForm" method="GET" action="#">
    Link:
    <input type="text" id="url" />
    <input type="submit" id="goButton" value="Go"/>
  </form>
  <iframe id="showUrl"></iframe>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

script.js

```
var url = document.getElementById('url'),
    showUrl = document.getElementById('showUrl'),
    goButton = document.getElementById('goButton'),
    theForm = document.getElementById('theForm');

function loadUrl(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  showUrl.src = url.value;
  return false;
}

theForm.addEventListener('submit', loadUrl);

url.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
  //You shouldn't need this since the form submits when you click enter anyway.
  console.log(e.key);
  console.log(e.which);
  console.log(e.char);  
});
```